# Вставить записи из json в mysql средствами python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Что то у меня не получается , выводить могу, а как это в цикле закинуть не понимаю.
Имеем вывод JSON:

```
user_json
  result
     [0]
       'mail' = "mail@mail.ru"
       'name' = "name"
     [1]
       'mail' = "mail@mail.ru"
       'name' = "name"
```

Как мне это добро засунуть в базу?

```
for i in user_json:
    db_ins = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="password", db="remover")
    cursor_insert = db_ins.cursor()
    sql_insert = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `mail`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, '%s', '%s');"
    cursor_insert.execute(sql_insert,(user_json['result']['mail'],user_json['result']['name']))
    db_ins.commit()
    db_ins.close()
db.close()
```

Помогите код поправить , не понимаю как в цикле все значения из user_json в базу кинуть.

Comment: for i in user_json['result']: и потом cursor_insert.execute(sql_insert,(i['mail'],i['name'])) ? ps странный у вас json...

Comment: Да, тоже хотел написать, что формально это не json, а фрагменты json

Comment: *Как мне это добро засунуть в базу?* Отдайте на MySQL прямо JSON. Сервер без проблем распарсит и распихает данные куда надо.

Comment: @Akina можно пример кода

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос: точный CREATE TABLE таблицы, в которую надо положить данные, точный текст JSON, который надо положить в таблицу (на 2-3 записи), и финальное состояние таблицы. Да, ещё укажите точную версию MySQL.